# Convert single row to multiple columns Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

```
SELECT ID,NAME,VALUE1,VALUE2 FROM my_table where ID=1 ;
```

The query would give me output like

```
ID|NAME|VALUE1|VALUE2
1|XYZ|123|325
```

But I want the output in the below format

```
ID    |1
NAME  |XYZ
VALUE1|123
VALUE2|325
```

My columns will be fixed and each time the result will be a single row, how can I modify the query to get the below result?

Comment: You can do this, but it's better practice to pivot the data in your client program.

Comment: check my implementation of [unpivot](https://github.com/sKwa/vertica/blob/master/UDx/PolymorphicUnpivot.cpp). Modify it to your needs.

Comment: I don't believe there's any v-sql functionality like this out of the box without writing a union for everything. Like @sKwa suggested you could load a custom UDF and unpivot that way. Relevant discussion here:https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/219577/vertica-sql-data-transformation

Comment: @colinwurtz, I actually already did it [here](https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/239423/unpivot-functionality). But who cares?

Comment: @sKwa pretty slick, I may try and use this

Comment: @colinwurtz feel free. I will improve it in near feature: support for all data types + performance issues.

Comment: @sKwa thank u so much this is what exactly i wanted

Comment: @Swathi8038, keep updated, I will improve function, so far its just a concept/pilot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/239423/unpivot-functionality/p1?new=1) example, it do exactly what you need.

**UPDATE on comment:**

> but what if i have multiple columns and rows how can i transpose

My UDF will do transpose/unpivot for each row, for example:

```
daniel=> select * from test limit 4;
 user_id | day_of_week | to_sample
---------+-------------+-----------
       1 |           1 |         1
       1 |           2 |         2
       2 |           1 |         1
       2 |           2 |         2
(4 rows)

daniel=> select unpivot(*) over () from test limit 8;
     KEY     | VALUE
-------------+-------
 user_id     | 1
 day_of_week | 1
 to_sample   | 1
 user_id     | 1
 day_of_week | 2
 to_sample   | 2
 user_id     | 2
 day_of_week | 1
(8 rows)
```

Comment: Thank u but what if i have multiple columns and rows how can i transpose

Comment: @Swathi8038: What do you mean? Can you provide an example? Or can you open a ticket on GitHub if some functionality is missing? My UDF will do `unpivot` for each row.

Comment: @Swathi8038: open a new question, because functionality that you are asking its - `PIVOT` and not `UNPIVOT`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach which should be ANSI compliant would be to just use a series of unions:

```
SELECT 'ID' AS key, ID AS value FROM my_table WHERE ID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NAME', NAME FROM my_table WHERE ID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'VALUE1', VALUE1 FROM my_table WHERE ID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'VALUE2', VALUE2 FROM my_table WHERE ID=1;
```

If you also need the exact ordering in your expected output, then we could add a computed ordering column to the union query, then subquery and order by that.

Comment: Tried this approach but if i have more columns it might become tedious

Answer (score 0):

this also should work

```
SELECT StringTokenizerDelim((ID || ',' || NAME || ',' || VALUE1 || ',' || VALUE2), ',') over (partition by null) FROM my_table where ID = 1
```